# Set a pointer value using reflect?

Tags: go, reflection

I have this piece of code, where I want to set the value of the pointer that is inside of a struct.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    value *uint64 // value that I want to modify
}

func main() {
    var i uint64 = 1
    pointer := &MyStruct{&i}

    elem := reflect.ValueOf(pointer).Elem()
    field := elem.Field(0)
    fmt.Println(field.CanSet(), field.Elem().CanSet())
}
```

Result:

```
false false
```

Unfortunately it is not settable. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field must be public. Name it to Value.